# what does "Porn" mean in these words?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-structure

on Reddit, I saw many communities named "Food Porn" "Earth Porn" "Album Art Porn" "Movie Poster Porn" and these community aren't about Pornography.
so what does "Porn" mean in these words? and what's the rule for structuring these type of word?

Answer (score 4):

Images of real pornography are designed to promote feelings of lust or desire. Images of tasty food, luxury cars, lavish holidays etc are also aimed at promoting desire and, by analogy are called porn not because they are actually pornographic but because they give rise to similar feelings.

Answer (score 2):

We see lavishly produced material, e.g. glossy magazines, advertisements, TV and video, etc, about houses, automobiles, certain confectionery, drinks, vacations, and we can talk of property porn, car porn, chocolate porn, wine porn, holiday porn. This is a readily understandable term, at least in the UK. No suggestion of sex or of excess or unhealthiness is conveyed by the term, although people like me who take a jaundiced view of advertising and media values may disagree about the last two. This use of 'porn' is clearly what the OP is asking about.

Comment: I have found something called a 'Cheeseporn cheese board' a $68 acacia wood cheese board with two cheese knives, which seems to be a brand from Barcelona  in Catalunya/Spain. However the same term in Google finds other things too, so maybe an unfortunate name choice by those Catalans.